# Mysql - Import a csv file with multiple fields into a single field using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, import

I have a csv file in the following format:

```
phone1,phone2,phone3
11111111,22222222,333333333
```

I have a table in a mysql database called "phone" with a single field called `phone`.

How can I import all three columns from the csv file to the `phone` field? Basically:

```
select * from phone;
```

should return:

```
phone
11111111
22222222
33333333
```

If I cannot use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`, is there another method to do this in mysql?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can mysql import a csv or other txt file into one column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554099/can-mysql-import-a-csv-or-other-txt-file-into-one-column)

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not. It seems that this requires additional steps. I was hoping to do this with one step. I know I can create a temp table, insert the data there and then insert the data from the temp table to "phone" table.

Comment: in can't see antither option and the solution is very flexible, you can switch to a stored procdure or do it in python or other laguages

Comment: yes, I thought of using stored procedure but when I tried it, I could not run LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE in sp because mysql does not allow it. As you said, I might have to just do this with other languages. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import your data into an intermediary table first and then split it into rows.

Let's say you have your whole `csv` line in a  table `import`

| line |
| --- |
| 11111111,22222222,33333333 |

You can do this by importing with newline (`\n`) as delimiter

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/your/file.csv'
INTO TABLE import
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n'
LINES  TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
```

You can now use `substring_index` to split the imported csv line. What you need to know for this is the number of entries. You can get this number easily by calculating the difference in length of the csv line and itself with all the comma delimiters removed.

From that you create a sequence of numbers which in turn you can use with `substring_index` to extract each entry.

This can be done e.g. like this:

```
insert into phone (num)
select
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(import.line, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) name
from
  (select 1 n union all
   select 2 union all select 3 union all
   select 4 union all select 5) numbers INNER JOIN import
  on CHAR_LENGTH(import.line)
     -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(import.line, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1
order by
  n
```

You can reach the same goal using the `recursive` CTE

```
insert into phone (num)
with recursive
    N as ( select 1 as n union select n + 1 from N inner join import
        on n <= length(import.line) - length(replace(import.line, ',', '')))
    select distinct substring_index(substring_index(import.line, ',', n), ',', -1)
num from N inner join import
```

Another interesting approach is using `json_table`. For that to work, you first need to transform your csv line into a `json_array`

```
insert into phone
select j.line
from import i
join json_table(
  replace(json_array(i.line), ',', '","'),
  '$[*]' columns (line varchar(50) path '$')
) j
```

All of these yield the result you wanted

```
select * from phone
```

| number |
| --- |
| 11111111 |
| 22222222 |
| 33333333 |

See also [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5be3f119ba0bf3f5eb91050e00664473)

Solution was adapted from different answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17942508/14015737) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18555090/14015737).